# Do I need to wait for my car to warm up before driving off?

Tags: road-vehicles, technology

I heard many times from friends that [after starting up the engine of a car you have to wait a few minutes for it to warm up before driving off](http://jalopnik.com/yes-warm-your-damn-car-up-if-its-cold-1678251730).
I also heard that this only applies to engines that include a turbo intercooler of some sort.  Is there any scientific data that backs this? What are the actual problems (if any) of not doing this?